# Triple integration. Cylinder and sphere

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$\int \int \int (x+y+z)^2\, dx\, dy\, dz$ in the region shared by the parabolic $2az>x^2+y^2$ and $x^2+y^2+z^2<3a$.

I am stuck on this problem. Really. I made all the two change of variables that is commonly applied, but nothing seems clear. As there is a symmetry about the $z$ axis, I decided to discuss using the cylindrical coordinates.

So this integral is equal to
$$\int_{0}^{\arccos(1/\sqrt{3})} \int_{0}^{\sqrt{3}a} \int_{(r^2/2a)}^{\sqrt{3a-r^2}} (r\cos(\phi) + r\sin(\phi)+z)^2 r\, dz\, dr\, d\phi.$$

I think this integral is right, but, as you can see, it is terrible to evaluate. Do you see any other alternative that is not so complicated?

Comment: Why do you have $\phi$ and $\theta$?

Comment: @user10354138 :) edited

Comment: Rotate by 45 degrees about $z$-axis gives a simpler version.

Comment: Any chance this works out better in spherical coordinates? The bounds work out nicely.

Comment: For sphere, is RHS $3a$ or $3a^2$? $3a^2$ would make things simpler.

Answer (score 1):

$ \displaystyle \iiint_R (x+y+z)^2\, dx\, dy\, dz$ where $R$ is defined by intersection of paraboloid $2az = x^2 + y^2$ and sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2 = 3a$.

Let's first simplify the integrand.

$(x+y+z)^2 = x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + 2 (xy + yz + zx)$

Can you see why the integral of $xy, yz$ and $zx$ is zero over the given region? First, there is complete symmetry about yz and xz coordinate planes. Given $z \geq 0$ and $x$ and $y$ are odd functions, integral of $xz$ and $yz$ is zero. Also integral of $xy$ will be positive in two octants and negative in two octants and they will cancel each other out, again owing to symmetry.

Given one of the surfaces is paraboloid, you are right that cylindrical coordinates is easiest. So we rewrite the equations of surfaces as,

$2az = r^2, \ r^2 + z^2 = 3a$

Now find $r$ at intersection of both surfaces. Say it is $a'$. Then integral can be written as,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{a'} \int_{r^2/2a}^{\sqrt{3a-r^2}} r \cdot (r^2 + z^2) \ dz \ dr \ d\theta$